# How to configure in Jenkins dynamically scaling Docker nodes on AWS Farscape?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins, aws-fargate

The Jenkins master is not dockerized and is not on AWS.
I want to add nodes (old name: slaves) that are on AWS, that auto-scale, and that have minimal infrastructure. According to Amazon's marketing blurb, I should use Docker on Fargate.

In AWS Fargate, I have 1 cluster called "default", which contains one service, "jenkins-service", which was made with the Dockerfile `jenkins/slave:latest` from https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/slave/dockerfile

I'll illustrate how I did it with screenshots.

- Went to https://console.aws.amazon.com/ecs/home?region=us-east-1#/firstRun
- Container definition: custom
  [image]
- Name, jenkins, image: `jenkins/slave:latest`, port mapping: 22 tcp
  [image]
- Leave task definition at default settings and press Next
  [image]
- Service: leave default settings and press Next
  [image]
- Cluster, again, leave default values and press Next
  [image]
- Let it run and after a while I see this
  [image]
- View Service shows me this:
  [image]

In Jenkins, on `$JENKINS_URL/configureClouds/`, I can add a Docker cloud.
I have to give it a Docker host URI and I cannot find that anywhere in AWS.

[image: Jenkins: Docker Cloud]